# Asp.net mvc razor with validate.unobtrusive

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, razor

```
Model----------------------
public class Test 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must Be Select ")]
    public string TestList { get; set; }
}

Controller-----------------
public ActionResult Index(){
    Test test = new Test();

    string code = "11";
    Dictionary<string, string> selectList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    selectList.Add("33", "33 value");
    selectList.Add("22", "22 value");
    selectList.Add("11", "11 value");
    ViewBag.TestList = selectList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { 
          Text = x.Value, Value = x.Key, Selected = x.Key.Equals(code) 
    }).ToList();

    return View(test);
}

View-----------------------
@model ~~~

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TestList, null, "--SelectThis--")
```

i use c#, mvc3, razor with jquery.unobtrusive
that code are cool
but has problem -- html source view

```
<select name="TestList" id="TestList"></select>
<select name="TestList" id="TestList" data-val=true data-val-required="Must Be Select">
```

i want second result..
how can i do??

Answer (score 1):

If you want the second result ensure that this `@Html.DropDownListFor` helper is inside a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Code, null, "--SelectThis--")
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Also passing `null` as second argument is unlikely something that will work. You probably meant:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        model => model.Code, 
        new SelectList(ViewBag.TestList, "Value", "Text"), 
        "--SelectThis--"
    )
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

and what I would strongly **recommend you** is the following:

Model:

```
public class Test 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must Be Select ")]
    public string TestList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TestList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var selectList = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "33", "33 value" },
        { "22", "22 value" },
        { "11", "11 value" },
    };

    var model = new Test
    {
        Code = "11",
        TestList = selectList.Select(x => new SelectListItem 
        {
            Text = x.Value, Value = x.Key
        })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        model => model.Code, 
        new SelectList(Model.TestList, "Value", "Text"), 
        "--SelectThis--"
    )
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: I'll never get anywhere when you're online :) (Also, I can't  believe I forgot the `SelectList`)